# PHP => var as string to check array[key]?

Tags: php

I have a var like this...

```
$var = '["continent"]["country"]["province"]';
```

and I want to check if the var is a key in a array.

Here's what I've tried, unfortunately without success.

```
if (!isset($array.$var)) :
     do...
endif;
```

Is there a native PHP way to do this? I'm not a PHP wizard, Thanks!

Comment: That's not PHP too. Where are you getting that string from?

Comment: I think this code not from php. Please check.

Comment: Do you want to check if `$var` as key literally exists in the array or do you mean if `$xy["continent"]["country"]["province"]` exists?

Comment: Yes, i want to know if $xy["continent"]["country"]["province"] exists.

If not, it is to be created

Answer (score 0):

If the format is definitely like that, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
// Convert into a proper PHP array by trimming the extra stuff and exploding:
$var = '["continent"]["country"]["province"]';
$var = trim($var, '["');
$var = explode('"]["', $var);
// Apply native array functions...
$key = "country";
if (in_array($key, $var))
    // Do something if present
    echo "Present";
else
    echo "Not Present";
?>
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/tLx7c3**

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
 
`array_key_exists($key,$array)`
 to test if the key exists in an array..
eg .

```
<?php
$search_array = array('stack' => 1, 'overflow' => 2);
if (array_key_exists('stack', $search_array)) {
    echo "The element is in the array";
}
?>
```

array_key_exists() is a php method which returns TRUE if the given key is set in the array. key can be any value possible for an array index.
You can refer the following document for this .
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    '["continent"]["country"]["province"]' => 'foo',
    '["big"]["fat"]["mama"]' => 'bar'
);

$var = '["continent"]["country"]["province"]';

if (array_key_exists($var,$array))
    print 'key is in the array';
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.
But how can insert the key in the array I when this does not exist?

Comment: To insert a new key value pair, `$array['["fine"]["new"]["shoes"]']='baz'`.